# Difference between subjunctive and conditional with examples

Tags: грамматика

Please explain the difference between subjunctive and conditional. E.g., in other languages it is quite easy

Conditional:

> I will not come with  you *unless* you behave yourself.
>   If you are creating a scene I am  not coming with you

Subjunctive:

> I wish you were here
>   I hoped he would have come

Please say it with examples as you always do.

Comment: Please make your question more specific. Are you asking about how to form subjunctive and conditional tense in Russian? Are you asking about when a subjunctive should be used and when a conditional should be used? Do you have any particular Russian examples in mind?

Answer (score 4):

Predictive mood is expressed through future tense with optional addition of conjunction *если* (or colloquial *ежели, коли* etc.), for factual conditions (those in your examples, expressed in English through "if" or "unless"):

> Не будешь хорошо себя вести — не пойду с тобой.
>
> Если соберёшься устроить скандал, я с тобой не пойду.

, or conjuction *пока* for temporal conditions (expressed in English through "while" or "until"):

> Пока не станешь себя хорошо вести, не пойду с тобой. // I won't go with you until you behave yourself.
>
> Пока ты столько пьёшь, я с тобой не встречаюсь. // I'm not going with you while you are drinking so hard.

Speculative mood is conveyed through past tense and particle *бы*, possibly prepended with conjunction *если* (if in the beginning of the clause):

> Если бы ты хорошо себя вёл, я бы с тобой пошла // If you were behaving yourself, I would come with you.
>
> Не собирался бы ты устроить скандал, я бы с тобой пошла. // If you were not going to create a scene, I would come with you.

, or through conditional verb in imperative (and without *бы*):

> Я пошла бы с тобой, веди ты себя хорошо // Were you behaving yourself, I would come with you.
>
> Не соберись ты устроить скандал, я бы с тобой пошла // Were you not going to create a scene, I would come with you.

Optative mood is conveyed through optative clause starting with *чтобы* and the verb in past tense:

> Хочу, чтобы ты была здесь // Wish you were here

Volitive mood is conveyed through volitive clause staring with *что* and the verb in future tense:

> Я надеялся, что он придёт // I hoped he would have come